# external capacitor selection for crystal circuit

Tags: crystal

I am using a 8 MHz crystal having 30pF load capacitance. The external capacitance (cx1 and cx2) value got from calculation is 56pF. If these value either reduced or increased what will happen??

Answer (score 1):

Small changes in load C will shift the frequency slightly (very slightly).

Large changes in the ratio of capacitance on the crystal terminals may stop the oscillator working, make it difficult to start, or unreliable at temperature.

With so little information, no schematic for instance, it's not clear which circuit elements exactly your numbers refer to. Try it. Try it starting, use a reduced voltage to stress it. Try it at extremes of temperature. If the frequency is OK and it starts and keeps running, use it.